# CSS3 letter-spacing animation on loading page

Tags: html, css

This is my first try with css3 animation. I'm trying to create a letter spacing animation in which the letters are closely spaced at first and then letter spacing increases. So far I've found a code which allows the spacing to happen on hover. How can I remove the hover and make the animation when the page opens.

Heres the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lventbau/

and the code

```
p {
    letter-spacing:-2px; 
    -webkit-transition: letter-spacing, 1s;
    -moz-transition: letter-spacing, 1s;
    -o-transition: letter-spacing, 1s;
    transition: letter-spacing, 1s;
}
p:hover {letter-spacing:2px;}
```

Comment: You might need to use jQuery with this to add the class on page load, then apply the animations to the class, leaving the single `p` element with no animation.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using webkit keyframes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish it with css3 animations [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lventbau/1/) :

```
p {
    letter-spacing:2px;
    -webkit-animation: myanim 1s;
    animation: myanim 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myanim {
  0%   { letter-spacing: -2px; }
  100% { letter-spacing:2px; }
}
@keyframes myanim {
  0%   { letter-spacing: -2px; }
  100% { letter-spacing:2px; }
}
```

You can find animation documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

Comment: I just have one more query. Is it possible to animate the text from the center. Right now it animates from left to right. Is there a way for it to spread out from the center. Thanks again :)

Comment: I gonna check that ;)

Comment: Enjoy : http://jsfiddle.net/Lventbau/2/ , thank's to scaleX (documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/transform) carefull it's not gonna work on ie9. For next time there a nice site for css3 : http://css3please.com/

Comment: Thanks once again! You're amazing!

Comment: If you want more amazing stuff you can check this blog ;) http://tympanus.net/codrops/